# I want to know how to choose between action and functions in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am feeling confused.I want to know if there is any advantages of using functions in qtp if the same task can be done by using an action?

Comment: This question could probably be improved by something like "What is the difference between a QTP action and a QTP function"

Answer (score 1):

Actions and Functions have different capabilities in QTP.
Actions have an associated object repository and data table and are often used for high level flows (for example adding a new user into the system).

On the other hand Functions are not associated to test resources (OR/DT) and have the advantage that they can be used from any test/action (without changing the overall test flow). Functions are often used to help achieve the Action's functionality.

Pick the tool that's more appropriate to the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Actions have its own datatable where as functions does not have its own datatable.
2. Maintenance of actions is difficult.As it does not allow to open multiple test simultaneously.
3. Each action consumes additional 197KB extra space.

Functions: 
1. Action can call the functions from the test if the Function Library is associated with it.
2. Space required will be the space taken by he script.
3. Functions are more flexible in case of reusiblity.

I would recommend you to use functions instead of action as maintainence is less and we just need to make the changed in the function library if there is any change in the script.